# identify sequences of approximately equivalent values in a series using R

Tags: r, sequence, categorization

I have a series of values that includes strings of values that are close to each other, for example the sequences below. Note that roughly around the places I have categorized the values in V1 with distinct values in V2, the range of the values changes. That is, all the values called 1 in V2 are within 20 points of each other. All the values marked 2 in V2 are within 20 points of each other. All the values marked 3 are within 20 points of each other, etc. Notice that the values are not identical (they are all different). But instead, they cluster around a common value.

I identified these clusters manually. How could I automate it?

```
        V1 V2
1  399.710  1
2  403.075  1
3  405.766  1
4  407.112  1
5  408.458  1
6  409.131  1
7  410.477  1
8  411.150  1
9  412.495  1
10 332.419  2
11 330.400  2
12 329.054  2
13 327.708  2
14 326.363  2
15 325.017  2
16 322.998  2
17 319.633  2
18 314.923  2
19 288.680  3
20 285.315  3
21 283.969  3
22 281.950  3
23 279.932  3
24 276.567  3
25 273.875  3
26 272.530  3
27 271.857  3
28 272.530  3
29 273.875  3
30 274.548  3
31 275.894  3
32 275.894  3
33 276.567  3
34 277.240  3
35 278.586  3
36 279.932  3
37 281.950  3
38 284.642  3
39 288.007  3
40 291.371  3
41 294.063  4
42 295.409  4
43 296.754  4
44 297.427  4
45 298.100  4
46 299.446  4
47 300.792  4
48 303.484  4
49 306.848  4
50 327.708  5
51 309.540  6
52 310.213  6
53 309.540  6
54 306.848  6
55 304.156  6
56 302.811  6
57 302.811  6
58 304.156  6
59 305.502  6
60 306.175  6
61 306.175  6
62 304.829  6
```

I haven't tried anything yet, I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dist` and `hclust` with `cutree` to detect clusters, but with unique levels at the breaks.

```
hc <- hclust(dist(x))
cl <- cutree(hc, k=6)
data.frame(x, seq=cumsum(c(0, diff(cl)) != 0) + 1)
#          x seq
# 1  399.710   1
# 2  403.075   1
# 3  405.766   1
# 4  407.112   1
# 5  408.458   1
# 6  409.131   1
# 7  410.477   1
# 8  411.150   1
# 9  412.495   1
# 10 332.419   2
# 11 330.400   2
# 12 329.054   2
# 13 327.708   2
# 14 326.363   2
# 15 325.017   2
# 16 322.998   2
# 17 319.633   3
# 18 314.923   3
# 19 288.680   4
# 20 285.315   4
# 21 283.969   4
# 22 281.950   4
# 23 279.932   4
# 24 276.567   5
# 25 273.875   5
# 26 272.530   5
# 27 271.857   5
# 28 272.530   5
# 29 273.875   5
# 30 274.548   5
# 31 275.894   5
# 32 275.894   5
# 33 276.567   5
# 34 277.240   5
# 35 278.586   6
# 36 279.932   6
# 37 281.950   6
# 38 284.642   6
# 39 288.007   6
# 40 291.371   6
# 41 294.063   7
# 42 295.409   7
# 43 296.754   7
# 44 297.427   7
# 45 298.100   7
# 46 299.446   7
# 47 300.792   7
# 48 303.484   7
# 49 306.848   7
# 50 327.708   8
# 51 309.540   9
# 52 310.213   9
# 53 309.540   9
# 54 306.848   9
# 55 304.156   9
# 56 302.811   9
# 57 302.811   9
# 58 304.156   9
# 59 305.502   9
# 60 306.175   9
# 61 306.175   9
# 62 304.829   9
```

However, the dendrogram suggests rather `k=4` clusters instead of 6, but it is arbitrary.

```
plot(hc)
abline(h=30, lty=2, col=2)
abline(h=18.5, lty=2, col=3)
abline(h=14, lty=2, col=4)
legend('topright', lty=2, col=2:4, legend=paste(c(4, 5, 7), 'cluster'), cex=.8)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(399.71, 403.075, 405.766, 407.112, 408.458, 409.131, 410.477, 
411.15, 412.495, 332.419, 330.4, 329.054, 327.708, 326.363, 325.017, 
322.998, 319.633, 314.923, 288.68, 285.315, 283.969, 281.95, 
279.932, 276.567, 273.875, 272.53, 271.857, 272.53, 273.875, 
274.548, 275.894, 275.894, 276.567, 277.24, 278.586, 279.932, 
281.95, 284.642, 288.007, 291.371, 294.063, 295.409, 296.754, 
297.427, 298.1, 299.446, 300.792, 303.484, 306.848, 327.708, 
309.54, 310.213, 309.54, 306.848, 304.156, 302.811, 302.811, 
304.156, 305.502, 306.175, 306.175, 304.829)
```

Comment: Jay, it's important that the clusters don't take values that aren't in sequence; so, in your method row 50 is grouped with rows 10ff; can we adjust the command so that it doesn't allow this? Otherwise I think this is the right approach...

Comment: @cathalcom We can make unique levels at the breaks, see update.

Comment: Thanks this is great. Can you explain what the difference is between the set of 18 clusters (the lowest level), then 9 (the next one), then 3? If there is a parameter in the clustering algorithm that decides how 'big' the clusters should be that can be manipulated? and what do you mean by 'level' and 'jump'?

Comment: @cathalcom That's what I meant with arbitrary. The length of the branches of the tree do matter though, and usually they are cut at a height where there is a lot of space to cut them [(Ref.)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/109428), which is is why it could make sense to cut our tree into four (see the dendrogram). Also check `?hclust`. BTW, instead of `cutree(hc, k=6)` you could also say `cutree(hc, h=30)`.

Comment: I see. Rather than specifying the number of clusters I want, it would make more sense (given my topic) to specify the range of the cluster. The one big cluster here has a range from 271 to 412. The nine small clusters have ranges of 18 points or so. So, specifying the permissible range of a cluster will determine the number of clusters the procedure gives you. Can you specify the range using the tools you have proposed?

Comment: @cathalcom No, apparently you got a misconception of the method. Again, read the documentation `?hclust`.

Comment: Thanks - the thing is it doesn't make sense to specify the number of clusters I want in advance - since that's the whole question ("how many clusters are in this series of values"). The only way to do that is to set limits on some aspect of the cluster (i.e. how many clusters of type X are in this set); so, if this method cannot allow you specify this kind of aspect (in this case, how many clusters that don't have a range greater than 20 points), then I suppose it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution iterates over every value, checks the range of all values in the group up to that point, and starts a new group if the range is greater than a threshold.

```
maxrange <- 18

grp_start <- 1
grp_num <- 1
V3 <- numeric(length(dat$V1))
for (i in seq_along(dat$V1)) {
  grp <- dat$V1[grp_start:i]
  if (max(grp) - min(grp) > maxrange) {
    grp_num <- grp_num + 1 
    grp_start <- i
  }
  V3[[i]] <- grp_num
}

cbind(dat, V3)
```

```
        V1 V2 V3
1  399.710  1  1
2  403.075  1  1
3  405.766  1  1
4  407.112  1  1
5  408.458  1  1
6  409.131  1  1
7  410.477  1  1
8  411.150  1  1
9  412.495  1  1
10 332.419  2  2
11 330.400  2  2
12 329.054  2  2
13 327.708  2  2
14 326.363  2  2
15 325.017  2  2
16 322.998  2  2
17 319.633  2  2
18 314.923  2  2
19 288.680  3  3
20 285.315  3  3
21 283.969  3  3
22 281.950  3  3
23 279.932  3  3
24 276.567  3  3
25 273.875  3  3
26 272.530  3  3
27 271.857  3  3
28 272.530  3  3
29 273.875  3  3
30 274.548  3  3
31 275.894  3  3
32 275.894  3  3
33 276.567  3  3
34 277.240  3  3
35 278.586  3  3
36 279.932  3  3
37 281.950  3  3
38 284.642  3  3
39 288.007  3  3
40 291.371  3  4
41 294.063  4  4
42 295.409  4  4
43 296.754  4  4
44 297.427  4  4
45 298.100  4  4
46 299.446  4  4
47 300.792  4  4
48 303.484  4  4
49 306.848  4  4
50 327.708  5  5
51 309.540  6  6
52 310.213  6  6
53 309.540  6  6
54 306.848  6  6
55 304.156  6  6
56 302.811  6  6
57 302.811  6  6
58 304.156  6  6
59 305.502  6  6
60 306.175  6  6
61 306.175  6  6
62 304.829  6  6
```

A threshold of 18 reproduces your groups, except that group 4 starts one row earlier. You could use a higher threshold, but then group 6 would start later than you have it.

Comment: Thanks - it's because I don't want the range of any cluster to be bigger than a set amount; e.g. 20 points. But your cluster 3 goes from 271 to 306. 

If you split them at row 41, you get two clusters that both have a range  <20 (271.857:291.371; and 294.063:306.848). Could you adjust your method to accomplish that?